# Make an image center on the page with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the latest version of bootstrap and I am trying to get my image dead center on the page in a carousel.

I placed the `container` class in the main div of the carousel but it is still off centered to the left of the page?

[image: Example of off centering of carousel]

My code for the carousel is below:

```
<!-- Main Carousel -->
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="assets/img/carousel/slide01.jpg" alt="Ants climbing on grass">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Ants climbing on grass
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Main Carousel -->
```

From what I found on the internet is that the `container` class is supposed to center everything on the page. So what has happened here, and how can I fix it?

I also tried wrapping the entire carousel around the following code, but the same result was achieved.

```
<div class="container">
 <!-- Carousel inside here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Bootstrap 3, class="img-responsive center-block" will do it.

Just add it for all your images like so: `<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/carousel/slide01.jpg">`

Comment: Where do you add this?

Comment: this goes before in all images like `<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/carousel/slide01.jpg">`

Comment: awesomeeeeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 0):

Try using the grid layout that comes with bootstrap. Add the following classes after "item-active" - "col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3"

```
<!-- Main Carousel -->
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
      <img src="assets/img/carousel/slide01.jpg" alt="Ants climbing on grass">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Ants climbing on grass
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Main Carousel -->
```

You might also try applying a class to the same div and set "margin: 0 auto;". That may also work for you.

Comment: I had never thought to use the grid with anything other than "this is left, this is center, and this is right" I've been undermining my ability for so long! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve perfect horizontal centering is to use `margin: 0 auto`. Here's what your code would look like:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel" style="margin: 0 auto;">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="assets/img/carousel/slide01.jpg" alt="Ants climbing on grass">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Ants climbing on grass
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't like that solution, you could also use this:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="assets/img/carousel/slide01.jpg" alt="Ants climbing on grass">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Ants climbing on grass
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, that uses a relatively new specification that isn't supported by all browsers. For more information on FlexBox, see [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/an-introduction-to-css-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

add this in to your custom css file

> .img-responsive  {
>       margin: 0 auto; }

Answer (score -2):

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: use this in div class "slider or any place"